# GAE BlobStore : After Uploading a file successfully, google appengine throws null exception when calling user.getEmail()

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore, gae-userservice

I am using Google blobstore service to upload a file. I did the following steps

- Login in to the application using the UserService
- I used the blobstoreservice.createUploadUrl(successpath)
- After the file is upload, the callback url 'sucesspath' is called.
- In this 'successpath' servlet, I am calling the UserService.getUserService.
- The above call return the User object as null

Why is the User object null, after the callback from the blobstoreservice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your code, thanks.

Comment: might be an idea to mention the actual language too! You know, as a hint.